# Pandoc basic HTTP authentication

Tags: git, azure-devops, repository, pandoc

I'd like to use Pandoc to periodically convert a markdown file into a Word document. The .md file and the embedded images are located in a protected Git repository in Azure DevOps.

I tried the following but it just dumps the Azure DevOps sign in website HTML into the .docx file.

```
pandoc -f markdown https://company.visualstudio.com/projectname/_git/project.wiki?path=%2Fdirecotry%2Finput.md
-o test.docx
```

Is there a way to use basic HTTP authentication with Pandoc to access the markdown file?

Comment: You'll probably need to use `curl` with appropriate authentication to download the file or to pipe it to `pandoc`.

Comment: have you tried `https://username:password@company.visualstudio.com/projectname/file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could clone the repo locally, and then run `pandoc` command on the local markdown file. When you run `git clone` command, it will pop up the windows to let you login DevOps.

Comment: Thanks Cece Dong! I was hoping there was another way, but that's probably the best solution.